# I am unable to connect to wifi network

Tags: wi-fi

I am using motog first gen mobile, i have upgraded to lollypop os, after that i am unable to connect to wifi router(netgear) in my room, it is not showing in the display, outside room other networks are showing in display, except my room network.
     please help me on this

Regrads,
Praneeth l

Comment: Have you attempted turning off the router, waiting a minute, then turning it back on? (this is a legitimate solution)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could try. Have you tried restarting both the router and the phone?

If it still doesn't work I would recommend trying to connect to your router using another phone or laptop.

If another phone or laptop can connect, I would recommend reseting your phone.

If another phone of laptop can't connect, you need to debug your router